# Adding a unicode escape to a dynamic string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode, escaping, next.js

I cant figure out how to correctly add a unicode escape to a dynamic string value in order to render emojis in React.

In my database I am storing the hexcode for that emoji (`1f44d`)

I've created a **styled-component** with the correct css to render an emoji

```
const EmojiWrapper = styled.span(({ label }) =>
  css({
    role: 'img',
    ariaLabel: label || '',
    ariaHidden: label ? 'false' : 'true',
  })
);
```

and the usage where symbol is equal to `1f44d` just displays `'\u{1f44d}'`

```
<EmojiWrapper className="emoji" label={label}>
   {`'\\u{${symbol}}'`}
</EmojiWrapper>
```

I've tried storing the hexcode as an escaped string `'\u{1f44d}'` but that still displays `'\u{1f44d}'` as opposed to the emoji.

If I hardcode the hexcode with the escape `'\u{1f44d}'` the emoji renders correctly:

```
<EmojiWrapper className="emoji" label={label}>
   {'\u{1f44d}'}
</EmojiWrapper>
```

As does

`{eval("'\\u" + {symbol} + "'")}`

I am trying to avoid using eval however as I've read it is a bad idea.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.fromCodePoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint), this method has been added to ECMAScript 2015. Here you will find the `Polyfill` in case of problems with the browser compatibility:

```
const symbol = "1f44d";

<EmojiWrapper className="emoji" label={label}>
   {String.fromCodePoint(`0x${symbol}`)} // encoding UTF-32/UTF-32BE (hex)
</EmojiWrapper>
```